# Data not showing up intermittently on the OpenTSDB UI

Tags: bigtable, opentsdb, google-cloud-bigtable

We are running some high volume tests by pushing metrics to OpenTSDB (2.3.0) with BigTable, and a curious problem surfaces from time to time. For some metrics, an hour of data stops showing up on the web UI when we run a query. The span of "missing" data is very clearcut and borders on the hour (UTC). After a while, while rerunning the same query, the data shows up. There does not seem to be any pattern that we can deduce here, other than the hour span. Any pointers on what to look for and debug this?

Answer (score 1):

How long do you have to wait before the data shows up? Is it always the most recent hour that is missing?

Have you tried using OpenTSDB CLI when this is happening and issuing a scan to see if the data is available that way?

http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/cli/scan.html

You could also check via an HBase shell scan to see if you can get the raw data that way (here's information on how it's stored in HBase):

http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/backends/hbase.html

If you can verify the data is there then it seems likely to be a web UI problem. If not, the next likely culprit is something getting backed up in the write pipeline.

I am not aware of any particular issue in the Google Cloud Bigtable backend layer that would cause this behavior, but I believe some folks have encountered issues with OpenTSDB compactions during periods of high load that result in degraded performance.

It's worth checking in the Google Cloud Console to see if there's any outliers in the latency, CPU or throughput graphs that correlate with the times during which you experience the issue.

Comment: The data exists, it just does not show up sometimes (see my original post) - but starts doing so after a while. Thanks for the pointer about compactions.